# Low-pass filtering raster with a mask - matrix

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, filter, masking

I have to do low-pass filtering with a mask - matrix:

```
1 2 1
2 4 2
1 2 1
```

This is my code

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb"

raster = "Stadiony_Clip_Clip1"

nr = str("_05")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
R = arcpy.Raster(raster)
lowL = arcpy.Point(R.extent.XMin, R.extent.YMin) 
cellS = R.meanCellWidth 

Rnp = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(R, nodata_to_value = -9999)
#A = [[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
Rnp = (1*Rnp[:-2,:-2] + 2*Rnp[1:-1,:-2] + 1*Rnp[2:,:-2] + 2*Rnp[:-2,1:-1] + 
4*Rnp[1:-1,1:-1] + 2*Rnp[2:,1:-1] + 1*Rnp[:-2,2:] + 2*Rnp[1:-1,2:] + 1*Rnp[2:,2:])/16.

R = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(Rnp, lowL, cellS, value_to_nodata = -9999)
R.save(raster + nr)
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")

print "KONIEC"
```

is my solution correct?

The output file gets a lock extension instead of tif, I think it's an error. How can I change this?

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: A new raster is being created which has a changed number of channels from 3 to 1, the source type has changed from unsigned integer to double precision and the pixel depth has changed from 16Bit to 64Bit

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Your output raster is called raster + nr which will be 'Stadiony_Clip_Clip1_05' which has no extension so will be a GRID, change nr = str("_05") to nr = "_05.tif" and your data should change to a GeoTIFF. I can see that you're dividing by 16 which should make your data at least a float, check the data type of Rnp before converting to a raster and saving. I am no expert in NumPy but from what I can see you're converting a multiband into a single band with this filter as the result of the calculation is a single value.

Comment: @MichaelStimson the output workspace is a file gdb, so adding a .tif extension will cause an error.